# Ansible: fatal: [test1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (62s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}

Tags: ansible

I have the below ansible script whre it got failed

```
- name: Download Java to Latest Version
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      become_flags: su
      become_user: root
      shell: |
        cd  /home
        wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" {{javaurl}}
        tar -xzvf ./jdk-*.tar.gz
        rm ./jdk-*.tar.gz

Fatal: [test1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (62s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}
```

but manually I can able to do it

```
ra@HS-PF1XLASF:/home$ sudo su
root@HS-PF1XLASF:/home#
```

Comment: are you running this ansible script as the `ra` user as you are showing in the example? If yes, then I don't think you need `become_method` , `become_flags` or `become_user`, just `become: yes` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your playbook with `-kK` then you only need a `become: yes` there.

I would guess that other `become*` parameters make the sudo to start the interactive prompt, which nobody is there to answer :)